# Rshiny popup won't appear under different tabs

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When creating a tab for my shiny app I find that I cannot reproduce my pop-up on click to produce a histogram plot. However, when I do not include a tab, this works successfully.

For example, the non-working implementation:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui =fluidPage(
  navbarPage(id="navid",collapsible = TRUE,
             position = "static-top",
             fluid = TRUE,
             windowTitle = "Test",
             theme=bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch="flatly"),
             "Some Test"),
  tabPanel('Hist',
           fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(numericInput("n", "n", 50),
                   actionButton("go", "Go")),
      mainPanel(
        bsModal("modalExample", "Your plot", "go", size = "large",plotOutput("plot"))
      )
    ))))

server =
  function(input, output, session) {
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      runif(input$n)
    })
    plotInput <- function(){hist(randomVals())}
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(randomVals())
    })
    
  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Whereas, the working implementation has the following ui implementation:

```
ui =
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(numericInput("n", "n", 50),
                   actionButton("go", "Go")),
      mainPanel(
        bsModal("modalExample", "Your plot", "go", size = "large",plotOutput("plot"))
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am sure your UI for more complex scenarios is not properly designed (i.e. elements nested). For example, the `tabPanel` has to be inside the `navbarPage`.

Both of your UI stop working when they are used with bootstrap 5.
In your case, only the more complex UI was used with bootstrap 5, with `bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch="flatly")`.

I think the problem can come from the changed data-* attributes in different bootstrap versions. It is on the shinyBS side.

Here working example with bootstrap version 4 and updated UI.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    id = "navid", collapsible = TRUE,
    position = "static-top",
    fluid = TRUE,
    windowTitle = "Test",
    theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = "4", bootswatch="flatly"), # Please test with bootstrap 3, 4 and 5
    "Some Test",
    tabPanel(
      "Hist",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          numericInput("n", "n", 50),
          actionButton("go", "Go")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          bsModal("modalExample", "Your plot", "go", size = "large", plotOutput("plot"))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <-
  function(input, output, session) {
    randomVals <- eventReactive(input$go, {
      runif(input$n)
    })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      hist(randomVals())
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```